# Wordpress - Customizing log in function

Tags: wordpress, button, authentication, customization

I'm a beginner to WordPress. I have learnt to install WordPress using XAMPP, and have started using themes and plugins.

Now I would like to develop a login function, like this [link](http://offpeak.my/restaurant/1509/touchwood-inc--sri-petaling). User can surf through the webpage without signing in. The sign-in form will pop up when user clicks on the "CONTINUE" button.

I am currently using plugin "Custom Login Page" for user login function (of course it will only ask me to log in or out my WP account), however it doesn't do as what I would like to have. I would like to have the exact interface like the link above.

Can anyone please shed some lights for me please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can have your login form anywhere. After submitting the login form, you can authenticate the user using wp functions

```
$login_data['user_login'] = $_REQUEST['name'];
$login_data['user_password'] = $_REQUEST['pwd'];

$user_verify = wp_signon($login_data, false);

if (is_wp_error($user_verify)) {
    // error in login
} else {
    // login success
}
```